# jQuery script to sum values on rows and columns

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have the following table structure:

```
<table width="960" border="1" align="center" id="activity_table">
<tr>
    <td width="192">Activity</td>
    <td width="192" align="center">Option 1</td>                        
    <td width="192" align="center">Option 2</td>
    <td width="192" align="center">Total</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Activity 1</td>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="text" name="activity_1_option_1" id="activity_1_option_1" value="0" class="col1" size="10" />
    </td>                        
    <td align="center">
        <input type="text" name="activity_1_option_2" id="activity_1_option_2" value="0" class="col2" size="10" />
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="text" name="activity_1_total" id="activity_1_total" value="0" class="" size="10" readonly />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Activity 2</td>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="text" name="activity_2_option_1" id="activity_2_option_1" value="0" class="col1" size="10" />
    </td>                        
    <td align="center">
        <input type="text" name="activity_2_option_2" id="activity_2_option_2" value="0" class="col2" size="10" />
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="text" name="activity_2_total" id="activity_2_total" value="0" class="" size="10" readonly />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Activity 3</td>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="text" name="activity_3_option_1" id="activity_3_option_1" value="0" class="col1" size="10" />
    </td>                        
    <td align="center">
        <input type="text" name="activity_3_option_2" id="activity_3_option_2" value="0" class="col2" size="10" />
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="text" name="activity_3_total" id="activity_3_total" value="0" class="" size="10" readonly />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="total">
    <td>Total</td>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="text" name="total_activity_1" id="total_activity_1" value="0" class="" size="10" readonly />
    </td>                        
    <td align="center">
        <input type="text" name="total_activity_2" id="total_activity_2" value="0" class="" size="10" readonly />
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="text" name="grand_total" id="grand_total" value="0" class="" size="10" readonly />
    </td>
</tr>
```

What I would like to do is to automatically compute the sum on each column and row.

I managed to write a jQuery script to compute the sum on each column, by adding colX (where X is the number of the column) as a class for the columns I want to sum, but I don't know how to do it in order to work for rows.

Here's my script:

```
$('#activity_table tr:not(.total) input:text').bind('keyup change', function() {
var $table = $(this).closest('table');
var total = 0;
var thisNumber = $(this).attr('class').match(/(\d+)/)[1];

$table.find('tr:not(.total) .col'+thisNumber).each(function() {
    total += +$(this).val();
});

thisNumber++;
$table.find('.total td:nth-child('+thisNumber+') input').val(total);
});
```

Comment: Do you know (in JavaScript context) how many activities and options you have beforehand? That would be pretty useful.

Comment: Yes, I know the exact number of options and activities. Actually the table is a lot bigger, I pasted just a sample for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without referencing any classes, names, or ids within the table.

---

The code below gets the total for each column.

It works by grabbing the `cellIndex` of each `td` on row 2 (`tr:eq(1)`), which *isn't* the first or last column.  It then filters all `td`s with a matching `cellIndex` on rows except the first row.  If there's an `input` element, its value is added to a running total.  Otherwise, we're on the last cell in the column, which gets the total value.

```
$('td:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)',
  '#activity_table tr:eq(1)').each(function() {
  var ci= this.cellIndex;
  var total = 0;
  $('td', 
    '#activity_table tr:gt(0)')
    .filter(function() {
      return this.cellIndex === ci;
    })
    .each(function() {
      var inp= $('input', this);
      if(inp.length) {
        if(!$(this).closest('tr').is(':last-child')) {
          total+= $('input', this).val()*1;
        }
        else {
          $('input', this).val(total);
        }
      }
    });
});
```

---

The code below gets the total for each row.

It iterates through each row, totaling its `input` elements.

```
$('#activity_table tr:gt(0)').each(function() {
  var total = 0;
  $('td:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)',
    this).each(function() {
    total+= $('input', this).val()*1;
  });
  $('input', this).last().val(total);
});
```

---

Note that [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is now preferred over [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).  If you remove `input` from the totals column and totals row, your event handler simplifies to this:

```
$('#activity_table input').on('keyup change',...
```

I recommend moving all styles to a stylesheet.  I've done so in my Fiddle:

### Fiddle

Comment: Hello, Rick! Wonderful solution! Sadly, I have to use inputs as shown in my first post.

Comment: I'm sort of a jQuery newbie as you've probably already noticed from my code sample. Can you please update that fiddle in order to work with inputs for displaying totals? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Rick! I know it works fine in your example, but when I moved the code in my app, I get NaN values in the inputs for the bottom totals. Do you know why? I haven't done any changes to your code, the only difference is that the real table has more rows and columns.

Comment: If you can post a link to your program, I'll have a look.

Comment: Sure, here it is [https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/948420/table.html](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/948420/table.html)

Comment: I see the problem.  The row with "Pachet de raportări" doesn't have any input boxes.  I've updated my answer and my fiddle.

Comment: Hey, Rick! Got a question: the client changed his mind and now he wants to dump the last column (with the total) and to have a single row with totals at the end of the table. Also, a user can add a new row in the table (by injection with jQuery, cloning the last row before the total row), and the totals must be updated if values are added in the cloned rows. Can the jQuery script be modified accordingly?

Comment: Here's an update fiddle, without the last column, and with a button to insert new rows before the Totals row.  It also changes the `keyup change` events to be delegated, so that the `input`s can be created on the fly:  http://jsfiddle.net/66h8jqdj/

Answer (score 1):

I adapted your HTML a bit. Having classes for all row/column total allows you to select them all at once. Avoid selecting elements with regular expressions as this will be really slow. If necessary you can use two classes like `column column123` which allows you to select the group or a single item by class name. To access the indexes from the elements fast I use `data-` attributes. If elements are generated by jQuery code you can also use JavaScript data objects ("hashes") or jQuery's `.data()`.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
var rows = 3;
var cols = 2;

$( function() {
    var grand_total = 0;
    var row_totals = {};
    var col_totals = {};

    // I think there should be better approaches on initializing these
    for( var row = 1; row <= rows; row++ ) { row_totals[ row ] = 0 }
    for( var col = 1; col <= cols; col++ ) { col_totals[ col ] = 0 }

    $('input').each( function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var val = $this.val() * 1; // the multiplication is to prevent string concatenation

        row_totals[ $this.attr('data-row') ] += val;
        col_totals[ $this.attr('data-col') ] += val;
        grand_total                          += val;
    } );

    $('.total.row').each( function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.text( row_totals[ $this.attr('data-row') ] );
    } );

    $('.total.col').each( function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.text( col_totals[ $this.attr('data-col') ] );
    } );

    $('.grand_total').text = grand_total;
} );
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr>
<td class="total row" data-row="1"></td>
<td><input data-row="1" data-col="1" type="text" value="1">
<td><input data-row="1" data-col="2" type="text" value="2">
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="total row" data-row="2"></td>
<td><input data-row="2" data-col="1" type="text" value="3">
<td><input data-row="2" data-col="2" type="text" value="4">
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="total row" data-row="3"></td>
<td><input data-row="3" data-col="1" type="text" value="5">
<td><input data-row="3" data-col="2" type="text" value="6">
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="grand_total"></td>
<td class="total col" data-col="1"></td>
<td class="total col" data-col="2"></td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, Daniel, but I can't seem to make it work. I get no erros in the console, but also no totals. Later edit: seems that `row_totals[ $this.attr('data-row') ] += +val;` was supposed to be `row_totals[ $this.attr('data-row') ] += val;`. Also `$this.text( row_totals[ $this.attr('data-row') ] );` must be `$this.val( row_totals[ $this.attr('data-row') ] );`.

Comment: After modifying your code as written above, the totals inputs got populated by values like "010101010", so I think the sum isn't computed correctly.

Comment: Oh, and also there are other tables in that page, so it's important to fit your jQuery code in an `$('#activity_table input:text').bind('keyup change', function() {});` statement.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to adapt the code to your actual software. I just wanted to show a useful approach. The problem with `+val` is that JavaScript does hardly distinguish number and string variables. I used the plus to indicate a positive number. That works in Firefox. Which browser do you use? I'll edit with a real sum.